# Refresh datatable content without reload or pagination change

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a C# web service returning a response like this:

> {"d":[{"A1":"something","A2":"something","A3":0,"A4":"N/A","A5":"/Date(1555626832993)/","A6":"something","A7":4},{"B1"... etc

And I fill a datatable with above data doing this:

```
//Load(); function
var a1 = data[0].A1;
var a2 = data[0].A2;

var htmlCode += '<tr><td>' + a1 + '</td><td>' + a2 + '</td></tr>';
$('#TableBody').html(htmlCode);
var table = $('#Tabla').DataTable({
    aLengthMenu: [
        [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
        [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
    ],
    "bDestroy": true,
    "aaSorting": [],
    iDisplayLength: 10,
});
```

I'm doing pagination automatically with the following code:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    table.page(pageAc).draw('page');

    if (TotalPage === 1) {
        table.page('first').draw('page');                                        
        timesReturned++;
        pageAc = 0;       
        clearInterval(interval);
        //CallWebService and redraw table with all above code
        Load();
    }

    if (pageAc === pageInfo.pages) {
        table.page('first').draw('page');
        timesReturned++;
        pageAc = 0;
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    pageAc++;
}, 10000);
```

The main problem is that I'm changing page fine but I'm not realoading table data until I call Load() function again.

There is a way to redraw of refresh table content without losing pagination? Or without doing again **"< tr>< td>" + a1 +** ... etc.